# JSON how to access entries within entries?

Tags: java, json, eclipse

Consider this:

```
Dogs {
    001{
        age{
            5
        }
    }

   002{...}
       ...
}
```

I'd like to ultimately find the age of a dog, however, I do not know how many ids there are, and which is going to be the parameter.

So how exactly can I read this JSON?
I assume it would look something like this jsonObj.dogs.(desiredDog.getID()).age, yet getID would yield either an integer or a string, and I don't know if Java would understand I'm trying to conjure up a key.

Comment: 1. Take a look at this library `Gson google` 2. if you want to parse it by yourself, you can develop a `Regex` to match all ages represent and read it using Java. So I don't know what you want to do!

Comment: I don't know what parsing or Regex mean. But I'm using a json simple, whatever that is, to read and write to the file.

Comment: Did you give a try to Gson google library?

Comment: use Jackson to read the JSON file and map it to Object and read the required fields.

Answer (score 1):

I am assuming you're using `org.json.simple`. All you need to do is iterate over the keys of *Dog* objects, obtain them and then extract their age.

```
JSONParser parser = new JSONParser();
JSONObject rootObj = (JSONObject) parser.parse(yourJson);

for(Object key : rootObj.keySet()){
  JSONObject dog = (JSONObject) object.get(key);
  int age = (int) dog.get("age");
}
```